# Question about positive operators: If $\mathcal{R}(S)=\mathcal{R}(S^{1/2})$, why $\mathcal{R}(S)$ is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space.

> If  $S\in\mathcal{L}(E)^+$ such that $\mathcal{R}(S)=\mathcal{R}(S^{1/2})$, I want to show that $\mathcal{R}(S)$ is a closed subspace of $E$.

Since $S\geqslant 0$, we have $\mathcal{R}(S)^\perp = \mathcal{N}(S)$. Thus, $\mathcal{R}(S)$ is closed if and only if $\mathcal{N}(S)^\perp\subset \mathcal{R}(S)$. So pick $y\in \mathcal{N}(S)^\perp$. Since $\mathcal{R}(S)=\mathcal{R}(S^{1/2})$, we can pick $x\in \mathcal{N}(S)^\perp$ such that
$$S^{1/2}S^{1/2} x = Sx = S^{1/2} y.$$
So, $S^{1/2}(S^{1/2} x - y)=0$, i.e. $S^{1/2} x - y\in \mathcal{N}(S^{1/2})$. Moreover, Clearly $S^{1/2}x\in \mathcal{R}(S^{1/2})\subset\mathcal{N}(S^{1/2})^\perp$ so $S^{1/2} x - y\in \mathcal{N}(S^{1/2})^\perp$. Thus, we have $y=S^{1/2}x\in\mathcal{R}(S^{1/2})=\mathcal{R}(S)$.

> My question why for all $y\in \mathcal{N}(S)^\perp$ there exists $x\in \mathcal{N}(S)^\perp$ such that
>   $$S^{1/2} y=Sx?$$

Notice that there is an answer here ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527901/if-m-geq0-why-overline-textimm-textimm-leftrightarrow-textim)), but in this question we give a different proof.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $M\geq0$. Why $\overline{\text{Im}(M)}=\text{Im}(M)\Leftrightarrow \text{Im}(M)=\text{Im}(M^{1/2}) $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527901/if-m-geq0-why-overline-textimm-textimm-leftrightarrow-textim)

Comment: Yes i see it but this is another proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathcal{R}(S)=\mathcal{R}(S^{1/2})$, there exists $x_0\in E$ such that $S^{1/2}y=Sx_0$.  Now let $x$ be the projection of $x_0$ onto $\mathcal{N}(S)^\perp$.  Then $x-x_0\in\mathcal{N}(S)$, so $Sx=Sx_0=S^{1/2}y$.

Comment: Why we don't work only with $x_0\in E$?, it is necessarily to work with an $x\in \cal{N}(S)^\perp$? Thank you

Comment: As far as I can tell, the proof would work just as well if you used $x_0$ instead of $x$.